# Writing a Json file, cell by cell into a google spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, loops, google-sheets

I am in the process of automating a process, in which I need to upload some data to a Google spreadsheet.
The data is originally located in a pandas dataframe, which is converted to a JSON file for upload.

I am getting to the upload, but i get all the data into each cell, so that cell A1 contains all data from the entire Pandas dataframe, in fact each cell in the spreadsheet contains all the data :/

[image: How it looks right now]

Of course, what I want to have happen is to place what is cell A1 in the dataframe, as A1 in the Google spreadsheet and so forth down to cell J173.

I am thinking I need to put in some sort of loop to make this happen, but I am not sure how JSON files work, so I am not succeeding in creating this loop.

I hope one of you can help

**Below is the code**

```
#Converting data to a json file for upload
csv_data = csv_data.to_json()


#Updating data
cell_list = sheet.range('A1:J173')

for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = csv_data

sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

Windows 10
Python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the data of dataframe to Google Spreadsheet.

  - In your script, `csv_data` of `csv_data.to_json()` is the dataframe.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

  - From your script, I understood like this.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the method of `values_update` of gspread is used.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.
csv_data =  # <--- please set the dataframe.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
values = [csv_data.columns.values.tolist()]
values.extend(csv_data.values.tolist())
spreadsheet.values_update(sheetName, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': values})
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the library of [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe) is used.

#### Sample script:

```
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe # Please add this.

spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.
csv_data =  # <--- please set the dataframe.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
set_with_dataframe(worksheet, csv_data)
```

### References:

- [values_update](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)
- [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe)

Comment: Hi Tanaike the second pattern worked perfectly, thank god for whoever made that gspread dataframe library, made it super easy and basically one line of code. 

Now I just need to format everything and it should be ready, thank you!

Comment: @user12239916 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.